# Rubocop: Error - rubocop returned exit code 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop, rubocop-rspec

I just cloned a Ruby on Rails project to my local machine to work on it. I have ran the command `bundle install` in order to install all the necessary gems and dependencies required for the project.

But a message keeps popping up in my log messages, which gets me worried. It is

> Error:Rubocop returned exit code: 2

I have checked the version of `rubocop` that I have installed and it seems to be up-to-date.
I have also done some research as to what might be the cause of this error, but I seem not to have any luck yet. I need some assistance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to RuboCop HQ commit message in relation to this issue
([Return exit code 2 if RuboCop fails due to internal error](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/commit/5e741368)), it was stated that "**RuboCop returns process exit code 2 if it fails due to bad configuration, bad CLI options, or an internal error. If it runs successfully but finds one or more offenses, it still exits with code 1, as was previously the case. This is helpful when invoking RuboCop programmatically, perhaps from a script.**"

After a more thorough review of my application, I checked the log message and realized that I was also having an error below the `Error:Rubocop returned exit code: 2`, which is `cannot load such file -- rubocop-performance`.

So I quickly checked my `Gemfile` and realized that some gems listed in my `Gemfile` that have `rubocop` as a **runtime dependency** have not been installed.

The full list of the gems are

```
gem 'rubocop-performance'
gem 'rubocop-rails'
gem 'rubocop-rspec'
```

All I had to do was to simply install the gems individually via my terminal

```
gem install rubocop-performance
gem install rubocop-rails
gem install rubocop-rspec
```

And that fixed the issue for me.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: I am using VSCode and I had to install them in the terminal. I am not able to add them to my project since it is a teamwork. Instead, I did `gem install <Gem-Name>`

Comment: Oh, @RogerPerez, that's exactly what I did, guess I missed the `gem install` command in my answer. I just fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! This should definitely be documented somewhere prominent. I spent the better part of four days trying to get this working. Getting started with Vim and ALE to replace an IDE as a Ruby developer may well trip people up here.

Answer (score 0):

I also face a similar problem with my VS code format. It was resolved after doing a `bundle install` from the vscode terminal.

Looks like the root cause was some of the gem dependencies of rubocop were not installed to the default gemset and were available only in my project gemset.